# Node.js and wss://

Tags: wss, ssl, node.js, websocket

I'm looking to start using javascript on the server, most likely with node.js, as well as use websockets to communicate with clients. However, there doesn't seem to be a lot of information about encrypted websocket communication using TLS and the wss:// handler. In fact the only server that I've seen explicitly support wss:// is Kaazing.

[This](http://github.com/zimbatm/nodejs-http-websocket/blob/master/lib/http/websocket.js) TODO is the only reference I've been able to find in the various node implementations. Am I missing something or are the websocket js servers not ready for encrypted communication yet?

Another option could be using something like [lighttpd](http://github.com/nori0428/mod_websocket) or [apache](http://code.google.com/p/pywebsocket/) to proxy to a node listener, has anyone had success there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TLS/SSL support works for this websocket implementation in Node.js, I just tested it: https://github.com/Worlize/WebSocket-Node/issues/29

Answer (score 2):

Well you have [stream.setSecure()](http://nodejs.org/api.html#stream-setencoding-213) and [server.setSecure()](http://nodejs.org/api.html#server-listen-156).

I'm guessing you should be able to use one of those (specially the last one) to use TLS in websockets since in the end a websocket is just a normal http connection "upgraded" to websocket.

Using TLS in the normal http server object should theorically also secure the websocket, only by testing this can be confirmed.

Comment: Be warned, this answer might be obsolete since an year has passed. I will try to update the answer.